# Problem persisting Recycler item positions into Room DB 'position' column with UPDATE query after drag and drop on displayed item

Tags: android, database, sqlite, drag-and-drop, sql-update

BACKGROUND:

My Room database includes a 'position' column to record the position in the recycler display. It is used to feed Livedata:

```
In the repository:
    
     var allFragments : LiveData<List<Fragment>> = fragmentDao.getAllFragmentsOrderedByIDDesc()


and in the DAO:
    
     @Query ("SELECT * from fragment_table ORDER BY display_position DESC" )
             fun getAllFragmentsOrderedByIDDesc(): LiveData<List<Fragment>>

In my Activity:

     override fun clearView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
                    super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder)
                    viewHolder.itemView.alpha = 1.0f
                    updateDatabase(from, to)
     }

     override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
                    from = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                    to = target.adapterPosition
                    recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemMoved(from, to)
                    return true
     } 
    
     ...

     fun updateDatabase(from :Int, to :Int) {
        fragmentViewModel.decreaseDisplayPositions1(from)

        var i = 1
        val j = (to - from)
        while (i <=  j) {
            fragmentViewModel.decreaseDisplayPositions2(from,i)
            i++

        fragmentViewModel.decreaseDisplayPositions3(to)
        }
     }
```

the relevant queries in the DAO are:

```
@Query("UPDATE fragment_table  SET display_position = -1 WHERE  display_position =  :from")
suspend fun decreaseDisplayPositions1(from :Int)

@Query("UPDATE fragment_table  SET display_position = :from +  :i -1 WHERE  display_position = :from  + :i")
suspend fun decreaseDisplayPositions2( from :Int, i :Int)

@Query("UPDATE fragment_table  SET display_position = :to WHERE  display_position =  -1")
suspend fun decreaseDisplayPositions3( to :Int)
```

The update works as follows, in dragging down (i.e. position value increasing), the dragged item position is set to '-1', then a loop is entered and then each successive item is dropped by 1 until the value specified as 'from - to' is reached, at which point, the dragged item position is set to 'to'.

PROBLEM:

Things work perfectly for any position being dragged over one item, i.e. position goes from i -> i+1 . It sometimes works for i -> i+2, and it fails for longer drags.

QUESTIONS:

1. is the problem the repetitive calling of the same queries with iterated parameters?
2. or is my code at fault ?

If I use something like

```
Collections.swap (mutableList, from , to)
```

I'm still faced with updating 'position' in the database.

3. I'm unsure if I can bundle all the changes into a single query to replace my second query (decreaseDisplayPositions2), something like:

   sql-pseudo-code: "UPDATE mytable SET position = (4,5,6,7) WHERE position = (5,6,7,8)"

Would be very grateful for any assistance / comments.